# How to close multiple browser tab?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I am developing a Web Application using `RichFaces`.

On the home page, having many page links and each link clicks need to show that corresponding page in new tab.

**Requirement:-**

When I clicked on logout button, that above page link `tabs` need to be closed automatically.

I tried in some way, but it could not be reached my requirement.

**JSP:-**

```
  <rich:panelMenuGroup>
      <rich:panelMenuItem>
          <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="return NewWindow('./../sample.jsp','Sample 1');">
              <h:outputText value="Sample"/>
          </h:outputLink>
      </rich:panelMenuItem>

      <rich:panelMenuItem>
          <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="return NewWindow('./../test.jsp','Test');">
              <h:outputText value="Test"/>
          </h:outputLink>
      </rich:panelMenuItem>
  </rich:panelMenuGroup>

  <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="--" onclick="closeTabs();"/>
```

**Java Script:-**

```
   var object = new Array(); 
   function NewWindow(mypage,myname)
    {
        var newwin = window.open(mypage,'_blank');
        object.push(newwin);
        if (window.focus)
          {
             newwin.focus()
          }
        return false;
    }

   function closeTabs()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) 
          {
              object[i].close();
          }
    }
```

This above code is working fine until the page getting refreshed, because when refreshed that `var object` Array is reset automatically.

Is there any other way to close the tabs.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Try renaming your var object to something else as object is a keyword in JavaScript so you are probably confusing the JavaScript engine.

Comment: Please try storing the array in some localstorage and retain it after the refresh.

Comment: @ jeff , tried but no use

Comment: @ Alexis Toby, Already tried with localstorage, but the array which contains windows object is converted into string thts a issue. I need windows object after stored values from object array in localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

@Alexis Toby, I tried with your code but got exception below where i marked in comment.

**I integrated your code in below:-**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">           
               var objectArray = new Array(); 
               function NewWindow(mypage,myname)
                {          
                   var newwin = window.open(mypage,'_blank');
                   objectArray.push(newwin);
                   localStorage.tabArray = JSON.stringify(objectArray);
                   if(window.focus)
                      {
                       newwin.focus()
                      }
                      return false;
                 }

                function closeWindow()
                  {
                    objectArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.tabArray); // In this part exception coming, why?
                    for(i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) 
                       {
                         objectArray[i].close();
                       }
                  }
   </script>
```

Comment: Can you please add your JSON all in this answer?

Comment: @Alexis Toby, which one?

Comment: After opening new tabs you will get some data in objectArray, that data I am asking.

Comment: @Alexis Toby,  "[object Window],[object Window]" This is what I am getting, after opening two tabs.

Comment: What is the value of objectArray at  *objectArray.push(newwin);
                   localStorage.tabArray = JSON.stringify(objectArray);*

Comment: @Alexis Toby, from that, I am getting the Windows Object like [object Window].

Answer (score 0):

I hope updating the script will solve your problem. Please try this.

```js
  var object = new Array(); 
   function NewWindow(mypage,myname)
    {
        var newwin = window.open(mypage,'_blank');
        object.push(newwin);
        if (window.focus)
          {
             newwin.focus()
          }
          localStorage.tabArray = JSON.stringify(object);
        return false;
    }

   function closeTabs()
    {
    object = JSON.parse(localStorage.tabArray);
        for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) 
          {
              object[i].close();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Here the localstorage converts windows object into string format, so that while getting values from localstorage after saved, I could not get as windows object to close the tabs.

Comment: I got this error in firebug "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" if i use the above option

Comment: The JSON is not parsed well then. Can you please show you sample JSON?

Comment: @venkatRaj I am sorry, I did not get you?